# Is these MSVC++ 2022 warnings on const false-positive?

Tags: c++

With the code below

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool MyComparator(const int lhs, const int rhs) {
    // More logic included here
    return lhs < rhs;
}

template <typename T, typename Comp = std::less<T>>
class seq_forward_comparator
{
    const std::vector<T>& vec;
    const Comp& comp;
public:
    static const std::size_t npos = ((std::size_t)-1);

    seq_forward_comparator(const std::vector<T>& vec, const Comp& comp = {}) : vec(vec), comp(comp) { }

    bool operator() (int idx1, int idx2)
    {
        // More logic here
        return std::ranges::lexicographical_compare(vec.begin()+idx1,vec.end(), vec.begin() + idx2, vec.end(), comp);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    seq_forward_comparator<int, decltype(MyComparator)> less2(vec, MyComparator);

    seq_forward_comparator<int> less1(vec);

}
```

On [MSVC++](https://godbolt.org/z/dojxYM6fe) I am getting warnings:

```
<source>(13): warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored
<source>(13): note: the template instantiation context (the oldest one first) is
<source>(29): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'seq_forward_comparator<int,bool (int,int)>' being compiled
<source>(17): warning C4180: qualifier applied to function type has no meaning; ignored
```

while [CLang](https://godbolt.org/z/ove7qxE17) doesn't issue warning.

In case I replace

```
    seq_forward_comparator<int, decltype(MyComparator)> less2(vec, MyComparator);
```

with

```
    seq_forward_comparator<int, decltype(MyComparator)*> less2(vec, MyComparator);
```

[MSVC++ 2022](https://godbolt.org/z/E3Wj4Ksza) stops giving warning.

Is this false-positive?

If not, what potential problem is signals except "excessive" `const` and in which way changing type from function (which is a pointer to a function, anyway) to pointer to a function solves this?

If so, what would be the best way to avoid it except suppressing the warning and passing explicit pointer to the function?

**Update**

Of course, solution with the replacement `decltype(MyComparator)` to `decltype(MyComparator)*` is wrong or in this case at least pointer to the function must be passed as a predicate, as this type states.

Comment: `const Comp&` where `Comp` is a function type is the same as `Comp&`. A function can't be modified, so `const` is redundant. The warning is correct but maybe not relevant since the `const` in the template makes sense for other types. A pointer can be modified, so `const&` and `&` are not the same thing.

Comment: @user17732522, but what changes with the passing the `decltype(MyComparator)*` instead of `decltype(MyComparator)*`?

Comment: It would be better for optimizer if you would wrap this comparator into a class. After this warning will vanish. So from this point of view this warning can be consider as useful (if properly interested). Also having there a reference is very risky. I would drop it.

Comment: Better godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/fseeqdx4P

Comment: @MarekR, thank you, solution with a class worked like a charm! Some questions: (1) since without reference passing pure function [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/eKs84ceoY) and hoped that `std::integral_constant` will help me here, but is [doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/f44e4YWEs), as well; do you have any idea, why? (2) Why having a class for comparator would be better for optimizer? What kind of difference it makes? (3) Is it really fine to store a comparator (not a reference) in `seq_forward_comparator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this false-positive?

No, for a *function-type* `Comp`, the `const Comp&` is the same as `Comp&`. This can be seen from [dcl.fct#11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct#11):

> The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. **In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.**
> [Note 4: **A function type that has a cv-qualifier-seq is not a cv-qualified type; there are no cv-qualified function types.** — end note]
> [Example 4:
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> struct S {
>   const F f;        // OK: equivalent to: void f();
> };
> ```
>
> — end example]

---

> in which way changing type from function to pointer to a function solves this?

A pointer type is an *object-type* and can be modified so for a pointer type `const&Comp` and `Comp&` are not the same.

Comment: Thank you. So, am I got you correctly that this warning should come only in case when a function (not functor made of class) has passed to the template?

Comment: @DamirTenishev Yes, only for a "function" but not for a "functor".  You're welcome.